# How to ls certain range of number

Tags: ls

I have a directory that contains fifty folders named F01, F02....,F05. I want to count the total file number in F25 ~ F48, however, the only way I know is `ls -1d F2[5-9]/*|wc -l` and then type `ls -1d F[3-4][0-9]/*|wc -l`, and sum them up. Apparently this is not the right approach and it also includes F49.

So, what's the elegant way to do `ls` in this kind of certain pattern?

Comment: you can use `ls F{25..48}/*`

Comment: you can find it in the *man bash* - Brace expansion (line: 926), its called sequence expression